# VB.NET Calculator; clearing textbox after an operation

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I'm working on a simple calculator and it's working but I face the problem to clear the textbox once the operation is done and I wanna start another one.
Let's say I do a sum and the result is 6, when I click on a number to start another operation it doesn't clear the textbox and I would like to know how I could do it?

Please keep your answers simple since I am a beginner.

This is the code I currently have:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim FirstNumber As Long
Dim Operation As String


'BUTTONS
'Numbers

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "2"
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "3"
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "4"
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "5"
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "6"
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "7"
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "8"
End Sub

Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "9"
End Sub

Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Zero.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "0"
End Sub

'Buttons "," "del" "clear"

Private Sub Button14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Dot.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + ","
End Sub

Private Sub Button17_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Del.Click
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text.Remove(Viewer.Text.Length - 1, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
    Viewer.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Sum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Sum.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(Viewer.Text)
    Operation = "SUM"
    Viewer.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Minus.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(Viewer.Text)
    Operation = "MINUS"
    Viewer.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Multi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Multi.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(Viewer.Text)
    Operation = "MULTI"
    Viewer.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Div_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Div.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(Viewer.Text)
    Operation = "DIV"
    Viewer.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Result_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Result.Click
    Dim SecondNumber As Long
    Dim Result As Double

    SecondNumber = Val(Viewer.Text)

    'Fx
    If Operation = "SUM" Then
        Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber
    End If

    If Operation = "MINUS" Then
        Result = FirstNumber - SecondNumber
    End If

    If Operation = "MULTI" Then
        Result = FirstNumber * SecondNumber
    End If

    If Operation = "DIV" Then
        Result = FirstNumber / SecondNumber
    End If

    Viewer.Text = Result

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Ty guys, gonna check them ASAP! ty so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a simpel global variable of type boolean, that indicates you want to clear the text before adding a number, like so:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim FirstNumber As Long
  Dim Operation As String
  Dim ClearField as Boolean = True  'At program start, you do want to start over at first
  ...
```

Then you should use a new sub to add text to the viewer, to make the code clearer and avoid repetitions:

```
...
Private Sub AddNumber(NewValue as String)
  If ClearField = True Then Viewer.Text = ""
  Viewer.Text &= NewValue
  ClearField = False
End Sub
...
```

After the field is cleared once, you set the `ClearField` variable to false, to avoid clearing the field again.
In the `Button.Click` event handlers you would simply use this sub instead of adding the text by hand:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddNumber("1")
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    AddNumber("2")
End Sub
```

and so on.
After calculating the result, you would set the ClearField variable to true, so the program starts over the next time you add a number:

```
...
Viewer.Text = Result
ClearField = True
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a flag variable at the start of the code. On the result click event, set the flag. The next time you click a number button, check the flag. If it is set:

1. Clear the text box.
2. set the flag back to 0.

In your result click event add this line after `Viewer.Text = Result`

```
flag=1
```

Here is a sample for a button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  If flag=1 then
     Viewer.Text = ""
     Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "1"
     flag = 0
  Else
     Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "1"
  End If
End Sub
```

Do this for every button.

Comment: Doesn't "flag" needs to be declared? I tried but, even not throwing any error, It doesn't works...

Comment: Of course "flag" needs to be declared. Declare it globally after "Dim Operation As String" as "Dim Flag As Integer"

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable to recognize if typing is sequence of numbers and operation OR if it is start of such sequence after result button.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim FirstNumber As Long
Dim Operation As String

Dim ResultPressed As Boolean

'BUTTONS
'Numbers

Private Sub Typing()
  IF ResultPressed Then ' Result button was already pressed. This number or operation typing is first button press after result button
      Viewer.Text = "";      ' so let's clear textbox
      ResultPressed = False; 
  End If
  ' If ResultPressed is false, nothing to do. Continue typing numbers ..
End

Private Sub EndTyping()
  ResultPressed = True;
End  



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Typing number or some operation fce Typing() will decides if clear textbox..
    Typing()
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' Typing number or some operation fce Typing() will decides if clear textbox..
    Typing()
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "2"
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ' Typing number or some operation fce Typing() will decides if clear textbox..
    Typing()
    Viewer.Text = Viewer.Text + "3"
End Sub


Private Sub Result_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Result.Click        
    Dim SecondNumber As Long
    Dim Result As Double

    ' Numbers and operation typing finished. 
    EndTyping()

    SecondNumber = Val(Viewer.Text)
```